# Batch Can't Set inside IF Block

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

So I am looking to expand this batch file to account for everyday of the week, im currently testing it with 1 day but once I get that finalized I can expand easily but I get to the issue where I cannot set values inside it if day statements and I tried setting expansion delay and using `!` instead of `%` but I get the same "missing" operator" error on the second line of the `if` statement. Does anyone have any thoughts for me? Here is the script: please start about half way in at the `REM if %DAY% EQU Mon(` line everything before that is just a reference need be:

PS: When I run it as posted with the `if` statement removed everything works fine thats why im confused.
PPS: at the bottom i added info as to what the Day.txt Files look like

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

date /t>nul
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ('date /t') do set DAY=%%i

    type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Mon.txt">nul
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Mon.txt"') do set MonHrWrk=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Mon.txt"') do set MonMinWrk=%%i  
for /f "tokens=6 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Mon.txt"') do set MonHrChrg=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Mon.txt"') do set MonMinChrg=%%i
    type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Tue.txt">nul
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Tue.txt"') do set TueHrWrk=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Tue.txt"') do set TueMinWrk=%%i  
for /f "tokens=6 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Tue.txt"') do set TueHrChrg=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Tue.txt"') do set TueMinChrg=%%i
    type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Wed.txt">nul
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Wed.txt"') do set WedHrWrk=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Wed.txt"') do set WedMinWrk=%%i  
for /f "tokens=6 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Wed.txt"') do set WedHrChrg=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Wed.txt"') do set WedMinChrg=%%i
    type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Thu.txt">nul 
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Thu.txt"') do set ThuHrWrk=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Thu.txt"') do set ThuMinWrk=%%i  
for /f "tokens=6 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Thu.txt"') do set ThuHrChrg=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Thu.txt"') do set ThuMinChrg=%%i
    type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Fri.txt">nul
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Fri.txt"') do set FriHrWrk=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims=?   :" %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Fri.txt"') do set FriMinWrk=%%i  
for /f "tokens=6 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Fri.txt"') do set FriHrChrg=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims=?   ." %%i in ('type "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Fri.txt"') do set FriMinChrg=%%i
REM if %DAY% EQU Mon(   
        set /a WeekHrWrk1=%MonHrWrk%+%TueHrWrk%+%WedHrWrk%+%ThuHrWrk%+%FriHrWrk%
        set /a WeekHrWrk2=%WeekHrWrk1%*60
        set /a WeekMinWrk1=%MonMinWrk%+%TueMinWrk%+%WedMinWrk%+%ThuMinWrk%+%FriMinWrk%  
        set /a WeekHrWrk3=%WeekHrWrk2%+%WeekMinWrk1%
        set /a WeekHrWrk=%WeekHrWrk3%/60
        set /a WeekMinWrk=%WeekHrWrk3%%%60`

        set /a WeekHrChrg1=%MonHrChrg%+%TueHrChrg%+%WedHrChrg%+%ThuHrChrg%+%FriHrChrg%              
        set /a WeekHrChrg2=%WeekHrChrg1%*60
        set /a WeekMinChrg1=%MonMinChrg%+%TueMinChrg%+%WedMinChrg%+%ThuMinChrg%+%FriMinChrg%            
        set /a WeekMinChrg2=%WeekMinChrg1%/100

        set /a WeekHrChrg=%WeekHrChrg1%+%WeekMinChrg2%
        set /a WeekMinChrg=%WeekMinChrg1%%%100

        set /a WeekHrWrkAvg1=%WeekHrWrk%*60+%WeekMinWrk%
        set /a WeekHrWrkAvg2=%WeekHrWrkAvg1%/5                                  
        set /a WeekHrWrkAvg=%WeekHrWrkAvg2%/60
        set /a WeekMinWrkAvg=%WeekHrWrkAvg2%%%60

        set /a WeekHrChrgAvg1=%WeekHrChrg1%*60
        set /a WeekHrChrgAvg2=%WeekMinChrg1%*60/100
        set /a WeekHrChrgAvg1=%WeekHrChrgAvg1%+%WeekHrChrgAvg2%
        set /a WeekHrChrgAvg2=%WeekHrChrgAvg1%/5                                
        set /a WeekHrChrgAvg=%WeekHrChrgAvg2%/60
        set /a WeekMinChrgAvg3=%WeekHrChrgAvg2%%%60
        set /a WeekMinChrgAvg=%WeekMinChrgAvg3%*100/60

        if %WeekMinWrk% LSS 10 (set WeekMinWrk=0%WeekMinWrk%)
        if %WeekMinChrg% LSS 10 (set WeekMinChrg=0%WeekMinChrg%)


echo.                   Totals:   %WeekHrWrk%:%WeekMinWrk%        %WeekHrChrg%.%WeekMinChrg%>"C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\sums_Temp.txt"

if %WeekMinWrkAvg% LSS 10 (set WeekMinWrkAvg=0%WeekMinWrkAvg%)

echo.                      Average:    %WeekHrWrkAvg%:%WeekMinWrkAvg%>"C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Avg_Temp.txt"          %WeekHrChrgAvg%.

%WeekMinChrgAvg%

copy /B "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\sums_Temp.txt"+"C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Avg_Temp.txt" "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Totals_Temp.txt">nul

del "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\sums_Temp.txt"
del "C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\Avg_Temp.txt"
REM         )
```

Mon.txt:

> Mon   10/24/2016  8:14    4:45        8:31        8.50

Comment: Use `!varname!` instead of `%varname%` for reference to variables defined in the same `()` parenthesized code block.

Comment: I know you have asked us to look at the file from half way in but it would also help if you provide the content of at least one of Mon.txt, Tue.txt, Wed.txt, Thu.txt or Fri.txt and try to explain what your lines between the last if and last copy are supposed to do.

Comment: with set /a you can use just the variable names instead of %var% or !var!. like so `set /a a=b+c`

Comment: You can select multiple tokens with a single `for` loop, which will drastically reduce the amount of code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JosefZ had it correct that was the issue, when i tried i also used the ! after the block ended and that is why it didn't work. Thank you all for your help with great advice!!!